# Private comments in CKAN under datasets

Tags: ckan

I'm having a little specific task. I need to have a simple textarea for comments under a dataset. I'm using data.gov.uk package (https://github.com/datagovuk/dgu-vagrant-puppet).

Comment inside textarea should be private and should be sent to administrator's email (configurable from Drupal).

What would you say is the easiest way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the 'easiest way' but in short you would:

- add a form to `templates/package/read.html` with a to be
  created action (for example `action="/dataset/{{ pkg.id }}/comment"`). You might add a condition based on user.id or something.
- create a controller method for this action that get's the comment
  from request and sends the email
- add a route map to your plugin that connects the form's action URL
  with the controller method, for example:

  `map.connect('/dataset/{id}/comment', controller="ckanext-<yourplugin>.controller:YourPluginControllerClass", action="send_comment",)`

I've done something similiar, and also added a modal box (based on bootstrap in that case) so that the form would appear as popup after clicking a link.

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you very much.